# How to insert delay between each requests in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I wanted to execute a Test Plan as Below.
Example : I wanted every http request should take delay of two minutes

- http_request_1,
- delay (2 minutes)
- http_request_2

All request are in same thread group

Comment: Did you try to create such test plan? Did you rad this http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers ?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

1. Create a transaction controller in Thread group
2. put all your http requests under this transaction controller
3. add constant timer (with value as 2 min) to transaction controller 
   (this way it will be applicable to all request within that transaction controller)
4. run your jmeter script

or if only 2 request are there then add only 1 constant timer in between both the requests.

Comment: IMHO you don't need transaction controller. You can use every controller you like. And if you have only the two http requests you don't need any controller just put the timer directly under a thread group.

Comment: @thuri The answer says the same at the last line.

Answer (score 54):

The simplest way is to add a single 'Constant Timer' to your thread group at the same level as your HTTP requests.

Right click Thread Group > Add > Timer > Constant Timer.

Set the timer value to however many milliseconds you need (in your case 120000), and it inserts a delay between all requests in that thread group.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

1. Create a transaction controller in Thread group
2. put all your http requests under this transaction controller
3. add constant timer (with value as 2 min - please find the 2nd screen-shot) to transaction controller 
   (this way it will be applicable to all request within that transaction controller)

[image: constant timer in http request]

[image: Set the 2mins in ms]

4. run your jmeter script

or if only 2 request are there then add only 1 constant timer in between both the requests. Please find below screen-shot

[image: between 2 requests]