# How to remain inactive till Web session expires

Tags: jmeter

[Update test Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfUuV.jpg)
I need to check the session expiry functionality implemented for AUT which is REST API. My query is how to remain inactive for specified duration so that session expires and also how to retrieve the response in Jmeter.

My Test Plan:

[image: 1]

Comment: you have a cookie you want to check it after expiration? what's the expiration time ? days or minutes?

Comment: expiration time is in minutes... I want to check the server response after session expiry

Comment: you can see how to delay in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22009999/how-to-insert-delay-between-each-requests-in-jmeter

Comment: @user7294900 i had tried with constant timer, but the test continues successively after a delay... in short session does not expire as we do manually.

Comment: Add your test plan to question

Comment: @user7294900 test plan image added

Comment: you need to check cookie after constant timer

Comment: can u please guide me on that... how to check and read cookie

Answer (score 0):

Add Think Times to Controller node:

[image]

Remove the one after **Login Transaction-Local**

Set in Think time a pause higher to the timeout:

[image]

Add after it a HTTP Request that should redirect to Login page if session has expired:
[image]

Comment: tried with Think Time... still all tests are passing and there is no session expiry though jmeter

Comment: What think time did you put ? Are you sure it is higher than session timeout ? Did you check in View Results Tree that the response is not the login screen or something else ? Check through assertions

Comment: yes. i had put think time greater than the defined session timeout value, also verified the response for the next request... it got passed as response was from login page without any error.

Comment: yes manually its working fine as expected.... but finding it difficult to automate

Comment: Updated test plan added pls check

Comment: You didn't apply the changes I described in my answer. Where is Test Action with the pause ? Where is the query that tests if users has been disconnected ?